# XAMPP Apache isn't starting properly?

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp

I am trying to start xampp apache but it is throwing the below error.

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 10:13:49 AM  [Apache]    This may
>   be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  10:13:49 AM  [Apache]
>     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   10:13:49 AM  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and
>   check 10:13:49 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   10:13:49 AM  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>   10:13:49 AM  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums

I tried changing the port but still it is throwing the above error.

Any help will be appreciated.

**XAMPP Version**: v3.2.1

**PORTS**: 40, 433

Thanks

Comment: From netstat i checked it's not used anywhere. @Arvind

Comment: Check if port 80(default) is blocked/occupied, required by apache. try this with cmd `netstat -ano | find ":80"`

Comment: It gives this result when i run in shell
netstat -ano | find ":80"
  TCP    192.168.10.4:50583     216.58.210.68:80       ESTABLISHED     9412

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Start Xampp Control Panel
2. Uninstall Apache by clicking on Apache Module
3. Uninstall Mysql by clicking on Mysql Module
4. Again install both module by clicking on Xampp Control Panel.
```

I hope I will work well

Comment: From where to un-install apache module?

Comment: did you start xampp panel ??

Comment: Yes i did started but checkboxes can't be selected i can just click start , config and logs buttons

Comment: in services there is no aapche module option

Comment: have you team viewer??

Comment: Please uninstall xampp and remove  and install again if possible..new one..

Comment: https://www.vrcworks.net/blog/fix-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly-in-xampp-application/ please see it and try